# Save a new sound from others android java

Tags: android

I have 3 sounds in the raw folder  sound1.mp3 sound.mp3, sound3.mp3 as could be saved in a single file on the sdcard in android java

sound1 + sound2 + sound3 ---> soundnew

```
byte[] bitmapdata = baf.toByteArray();
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), music1.mp3);
FileOutputStream fos;
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fos.write(bitmapdata ); 
    fos.flush(); 
    fos.close(); 
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // handle exception 
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle exception 
}
```

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried?

Comment: the problem is to get you to load several sounds followed  
byte[] bitmapdata  = baf.toByteArray();


File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), music1.mp3);
FileOutputStream fos;

try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fos.write(bitmapdata  );
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // handle exception
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle exception
}